# Getting error on Facebook share using Web dialog on Android " An error occurred, Please try later

Tags: android, facebook

I am facing some issue in facebook share using web dialog. Facebook is prompting error message that "An error occurred, Please try later."  As onCompleteListener is getting called after clicking on ok on error message dialog. I am not able to find the error code.

Same application is working fine for the Facebook native dialog.

I have also tried same code with different facebook app id and it is working fine. So it doesn't look any code related issue, but related to the application setting on Facebook.

In my app id, I have set app domain, site url and mobile site url. Do we need to send some other parameters as well if we are setting app domain, site url and mobile site url.

Please suggest some solution.

```
    Bundle params = new Bundle();
    params.putString("name", mShareText);
    params.putString("caption","Build");
    params.putString("description", mContext.getString(R.string.social_preconfigured_text));       
    params.putString("link", mShareUrl);

    if(mShareImageUrl!=null){
        params.putString("picture", mShareImageUrl);
    }
    else{
        params.putString("picture", " ");
    }

    // Invoke the dialog
    WebDialog feedDialog = (
            new WebDialog.FeedDialogBuilder(this,
                    Session.getActiveSession(),
                    params))
                    .setOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(Bundle values, FacebookException error) {
                            if (error == null) {
                                Toast.makeText(mContext, mContext.getString(R.string.social_success_text), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                            else{
                                Toast.makeText(mContext, mContext.getString(R.string.social_failure_text), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }
                    }).build();
    feedDialog.show();
```

Thanks,
Manish

Comment: Can you try to rephrase your question title, and give some codes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dificult to say without error or code but I use facebook dialog like:

```
 @Override
    public void requestPostDialog(Bundle bundle, OnPostingCompleteListener onPostingCompleteListener) {
        super.requestPostDialog(bundle, onPostingCompleteListener);
        if (FacebookDialog.canPresentShareDialog(mSocialNetworkManager.getActivity(),
                FacebookDialog.ShareDialogFeature.SHARE_DIALOG)) {
            FacebookDialog shareDialog = new FacebookDialog.ShareDialogBuilder(mSocialNetworkManager.getActivity())
                    .setLink(bundle.getString(BUNDLE_LINK))
                    .setDescription(bundle.getString(BUNDLE_MESSAGE))
                    .setName(bundle.getString(BUNDLE_NAME))
                    .setApplicationName(bundle.getString(BUNDLE_APP_NAME))
                    .setCaption(bundle.getString(BUNDLE_CAPTION))
                    .setPicture(bundle.getString(BUNDLE_PICTURE))
//                    .setFriends(bundle.getStringArrayList(DIALOG_FRIENDS))
                    .build();
            mUILifecycleHelper.trackPendingDialogCall(shareDialog.present());
        } else {
            publishFeedDialog(bundle);
        }
    }

    private void publishFeedDialog(Bundle bundle) {
        Bundle params = new Bundle();
        params.putString("name", bundle.getString(BUNDLE_NAME));
        params.putString("caption", bundle.getString(BUNDLE_CAPTION));
        params.putString("description", bundle.getString(BUNDLE_MESSAGE));
        params.putString("link", bundle.getString(BUNDLE_LINK));
        params.putString("picture", bundle.getString(BUNDLE_PICTURE));

        WebDialog feedDialog = (
                new WebDialog.FeedDialogBuilder(mSocialNetworkManager.getActivity(),
                        Session.getActiveSession(),
                        params))
                .setOnCompleteListener(new WebDialog.OnCompleteListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(Bundle values,
                                           FacebookException error) {
                        if (error == null) {
                            final String postId = values.getString("post_id");
                            if (postId != null) {
                                ((OnPostingCompleteListener) mLocalListeners.get(REQUEST_POST_DIALOG)).onPostSuccessfully(getID());
                            } else {
                                mLocalListeners.get(REQUEST_POST_DIALOG).onError(getID(),
                                        REQUEST_POST_DIALOG, "Canceled", null);
                            }
                        } else {
                            mLocalListeners.get(REQUEST_POST_DIALOG).onError(getID(),
                                    REQUEST_POST_DIALOG, "Canceled: " + error.toString(), null);
                        }
                        mLocalListeners.remove(REQUEST_POST_DIALOG);
                    }
                })
                .build();
        feedDialog.show();
    }
```

Comment: @Ekondard, I have added my code snippet. Please suggest how to check the error code. In onComplete, I am not getting any error code. It is getting called only after clicking ok on error dialog.

Comment: Finally I have got the solution. In Facebook App Settings -->Migration tab, someone had set the Stream post URL security toggle. Because of which I was facing this issue.

Comment: Are you saying that the WebDialog depends on the FB APK? From https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/share#linkfeed "The Share dialog can't be displayed if people don't have the Facebook for Android app installed. In that case we recommend you fall back to the Feed Dialog, a web dialog that doesn't require the Facebook app to be installed."